# How to display thumbnail of YouTube Videos in Android

Tags: android, youtube

I writing an app where i want to display a list of YouTube videos. But I want the list to display the video title with some other info but also show a thumbnail of the video like it does when we go **www.youtube.com**

Can someone help me please on How to display the thumbnail for a video URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. Parse video ID from the URL: this is the 'v' parameter in URL. I.e. 'xAiiwSXVRiw' in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAiiwSXVRiw
2. Get the video metadata via Youtube Gdata URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xAiiwSXVRiw
3. Parse the XML that you get back and look for `<media:thumbnail url='..'>`. The 'url' attribute contains to the thumbnail url.

Comment: This answer is obsolete

Comment: OBSOLETE answer. URL responds with - "No longer available"

Answer (score 47):

With the Combination of Two Accepted Answer

[How to make YouTube video thumbnails in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842839/1318946)

and

[How to get video thumbnail of youtube video in android list in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655786/1318946)

Finally You just have to play with **ID** of **YOUTUBE URL** only.

I found one [PHP Answer for same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/1318946) in that they have described like:

Each YouTube video has 4 generated images. They are predictably formatted as follows:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images. The default thumbnail image (ie. one of `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`) is:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

There is also a medium quality version of the thumbnail, using a url similar to the HQ:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

For the standard definition version of the thumbnail, use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

All of the above urls are available over https too. Just change `http` to `https` in any of the above urls.

Additionally, the slightly shorter hostname **`i3.ytimg.com`** works in place of **`img.youtube.com`** in the example urls above.

## Example:

I have one URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU

Now I will just take **ID** from URL i.e.: **-OKrloDzGpU**

### Medium Image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/-OKrloDzGpU/mqdefault.jpg

[image]

### HD Image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/-OKrloDzGpU/hqdefault.jpg

[image]

## Load Images in Android using Glide or Picasso:

```
// Picasso        
Picasso.with(context)
       .load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/-OKrloDzGpU/mqdefault.jpg")
       .into(imageView);

// Glide
Glide.with(this)
     .load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/-OKrloDzGpU/mqdefault.jpg")
     .into(imageView);
```

Thank you. Hope it will helps you all.

Comment: do you know what additional info is required to be presented on youtube thumbnail? Smth like youtube tm, youtube "play" icon, and etc.

Comment: Didn't you have any problem with the delay on the response ?

Comment: Works so well! Thanks much! 

Answer (score 15):

> If you have URL of Youtube video. Use below code to get medium / high
>   quality thumbnail URL

```
        String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tResEeK6P5I"
        String videoId = url.split("v=")[1]; //you will get this video id "tResEeK6P5I"

        String thumbnailMq = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoId+/mqdefault.jpg //medium quality thumbnail

        String thumbnailHq = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoId+/hqdefault.jpg //high quality thumbnail

        //your final urls will be like 
        http://img.youtube.com/vi/tResEeK6P5I/mqdefault.jpg
        http://img.youtube.com/vi/tResEeK6P5I/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helpful to use image instead of slow loading youtTube API thumbnail

Comment: "/mqdefault.jpg"; 
"/hqdefault.jpg";

Answer (score 3):

Link to download Glide jar file
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.6.0

```
String url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoURL.split("\\=")[1]+"/0.jpg";
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but it is still coming in the top Google's search answers, so this us how I did it with the Android YouTube API.

```
YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
thumbnail.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, 
                                        YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(youtubeID);
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                //need to release the loader!!!
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, 
                                         YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                //need to release the loader!!!
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
            }
        });
     }

     @Override
     public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, 
                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
     //handle error here
     }
});
```

`YOUTUBE_API_KEY` get your api key in [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

`youtubeID` You need to use the video's ID not full URL.

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary).

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers are doing string manipulation which is not needed. You can get the if the id very easily using `Uri`

Kotlin

```
val videoId = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ").getQueryParameter("v")
val thumbnailUri = Uri.parse("https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/0.jpg")
Glide.with(this).load(thumbnailUri).into(imageView)
```

Java

```
String videoId = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ").getQueryParameter("v");
Uri thumbnailUri = Uri.parse("https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/0.jpg");
Glide.with(this).load(thumbnailUri).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want high quality thumbnail but not available for all video**

```
Width | Height | URL
------|--------|----
640   | 480    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/sd1.jpg
640   | 480    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/sd2.jpg
640   | 480    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/sd3.jpg
640   | 480    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/sddefault.jpg
1280  | 720    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/hq720.jpg
1920  | 1080   | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

**if you want thumbnail that available for all video (relatively low quality)**

```
Width | Height | URL
------|--------|----
120   | 90     | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/1.jpg
120   | 90     | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/2.jpg
120   | 90     | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/3.jpg
120   | 90     | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/default.jpg
320   | 180    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/mq1.jpg
320   | 180    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/mq2.jpg
320   | 180    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/mq3.jpg
320   | 180    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/mqdefault.jpg
480   | 360    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/0.jpg
480   | 360    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/hq1.jpg
480   | 360    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/hq2.jpg
480   | 360    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/hq3.jpg
480   | 360    | https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/hqdefault.jpg
```

**So Maximum quality thumbnail that available for all video is 480x360.**

you can use link :`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/0.jpg`

```java
String videoId = IfXNjuoqt0Q;
String thumnailLink = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/"+videoId+"/0.jpg";
```

[image]

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IfXNjuoqt0Q/0.jpg

**To load image in Android**

```java
// Picasso        
Picasso.with(context)
       .load("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IfXNjuoqt0Q/0.jpg")
       .into(imageView);

// Glide
Glide.with(this)
     .load("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IfXNjuoqt0Q/0.jpg")
     .into(imageView);
```

--------Upto that already answer above------

### If you want to remove black-bar from thumbnail 480x360 (maximum quality image that available for all video in youtube),but problem its come with black-bar

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ThumbnailHandler {

    public static Bitmap RemoveBlackBar(Bitmap bitmap){

        if (bitmap.getWidth() == 480 && bitmap.getHeight() == 360 ){

            int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
            int[] pixels_out = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];

            // get pixel array from source
            bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            for (int y=0; y<270; y++){

                for (int x=0; x < bitmap.getWidth() ; x++){
                    pixels_out [y * bitmap.getWidth() + x] = pixels [(y+45) * bitmap.getWidth() + x];
                }
            }

            Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), 270, bitmap.getConfig());
            bmOut.setPixels(pixels_out, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 270);


            return bmOut;
        }else {
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("shabir", "err: "+e );
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void getYtThumbnail_480_270(String url,YtThumbnailDownloadListener listener){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(url);
                bitmap = RemoveBlackBar(bitmap);
                listener.onThumbnailDownloaded(bitmap);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void getYtThumbnail_480_270(String url, ImageView target, Activity activity){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(url);
                Bitmap finalBitmap = RemoveBlackBar(bitmap);
                activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {

                    target.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);

                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public interface YtThumbnailDownloadListener{
        void onThumbnailDownloaded(Bitmap bitmap);
    }
}
```

**copy above class in to your project**

Above class convert 480x360 Thumbnail to 480x270 to remove black bar,

**To load image in Android**

```java
// url
url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IfXNjuoqt0Q/0.jpg";


// call to load thumbnail in Image view        
ThumbnailHandler.getYtThumbnail_480_270(url,
                                        imageView,
                                        MainActivity.this);

// call to download thumbnail in bitmap format
ThumbnailHandler.getYtThumbnail_480_270(url, new ThumbnailHandler.YtThumbnailDownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailDownloaded(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        // Use thumbnail bitmap
                    }
                });
```

[image]

**Maximum quality thumbnail (480x270), available for all video , without black bar**

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late for this Answer, but in case anyone needs help this can be helpful, let's get started:

from the answer of [Shailesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26479975/10752962) and [Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674147/10752962), i have created new answer which can be helpful for youtube url's when you have these three kind of urls(all three videos are same just url format is different):

1. `https://youtu.be/Fs8fsrngI3Q`
2. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs8fsrngI3Q&feature=youtu.be`
3. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs8fsrngI3Q&ab_channel=SoftwareTestingAndAutomation`

and you can use given method to get thumbnail of video:

```
public static String extractYoutubeId(String url) {
    String id = "";
    try {
        if (url.contains("youtu.be/")) {
            return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        }

        String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
        if (query == null) return "";

        String[] param = query.split("&");
        for (String row : param) {
            String[] param1 = row.split("=");
            if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                id = param1[1];
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Use this method like this:

```
String videoId = extractYoutubeId(videoUrl);
videoThumbUrl = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg";
```