# How to make YouTube video thumbnails in android?

Tags: android, youtube

In my android Activity I want to play video from YouTube through YouTube application or some other. For that I want to load thumbnails of the video in my activity.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried to start on your own?

Comment: How isn't it working? SO won't just give you answers to unspecific problems.

Comment: I want to know is it possible or not?

Comment: Video thumbnail from video file is available. I want to know is it possible from youtube

Comment: You also asked how, which seems to be a request for code. But I can always be wrong.

Comment: No, I don't have code. That's what I'm thinking is off topic. No matter, @tom edited.

Comment: am geting the v=id from the youtube but how to convert drawable and set drawable to imageview .please help me...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

YouTube puts the thumbnails of the video at a specific predictable URL. It would be a bit of a pain, but I'm sure you could find a way to display the images from the URL, or to download them and then display them.

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150409235002/https://alamoxie.com/blog/web-design/add-youtube-thumbnails/)'s information on my blog on what those thumbnail URLs are.

I'll copy and paste what I wrote in the blog post:

Look at the link for the video–for example, `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDFUdMvacI0`

Take the `video ID`… the portion after `“v=”`, in this case `GDFUdMvacI0`. If the URL is longer than that, only go until the next ampersand. For example, `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDFUdMvacI0&feature=youtu.be` is the same, `GDFUdMvacI0`.

Then just substitute your video ID for the video ID in the following URLs to these thumbnail images:

- http://img.youtube.com/vi/GDFUdMvacI0/0.jpg
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/GDFUdMvacI0/1.jpg
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/GDFUdMvacI0/2.jpg
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/GDFUdMvacI0/3.jpg

`0.jpg` is a full-sized image. The other three are very small (120×90) and are taken automatically by YouTube from three certain points in the video.

Comment: how can get programmatically that video id?

Comment: That depends on what information you are starting with. I know nothing about your specific scenario, so I'm afraid I can't help you there. Please revise your question to include more details of what you are doing--are you trying to parse the video ID out of a URL? Are you submitting a new YouTube video through an API? Or what?

Comment: How to get youtube playlist thumbnail url?

Comment: Instead of "0, 1, 2, 3..." for the quality use this instead "default", "mqdefault", "hqdefault" or "maxresdefault".
The quality "maxresdefault" gives you the highest resolution.

Answer (score 28):

- Download picasso jar file and put that jar file in "libs" folder
- Use picasso to download image
- Use method `extractYoutubeId(url)`  to extract youtube id from YoutubeVideo Url

To get image of youtube video use  given link and put youtube id in that url as below: `"http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+extractYoutubeId(url)+"/0.jpg"`

Youtube_Video_thumnail

```
    package com.app.download_video_demo;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


    // get Picasso jar file and put that jar file in libs folder

    public class Youtube_Video_thumnail extends Activity
    {
        ImageView iv_youtube_thumnail,iv_play;
        String videoId;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.setContentView(R.layout.youtube_video_activity);

            init();

            try 
            {
                videoId=extractYoutubeId("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7UxjpUaL3Y");

                Log.e("VideoId is->","" + videoId);

                String img_url="http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoId+"/0.jpg"; // this is link which will give u thumnail image of that video

                // picasso jar file download image for u and set image in imagview

                Picasso.with(Youtube_Video_thumnail.this)
                .load(img_url) 
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 
                .into(iv_youtube_thumnail);

            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void init()
        {
            iv_youtube_thumnail=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_thumnail);
            iv_play=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_play_pause);
        }

        // extract youtube video id and return that id
        // ex--> "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7UxjpUaL3Y"
        // videoid is-->t7UxjpUaL3Y


        public String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            String[] param = query.split("&");
            String id = null;
            for (String row : param) {
                String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                    id = param1[1];
                }
            }
            return id;
        }

    }
```

youtube_video_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/webvideo_layout2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_thumnail"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_play_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_play" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can I run the thumbnail by following the instructions?

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
public static String getYoutubeThumbnailUrlFromVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
   return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+getYoutubeVideoIdFromUrl(videoUrl) + "/0.jpg";
}

public static String getYoutubeVideoIdFromUrl(String inUrl) {
   inUrl = inUrl.replace("&feature=youtu.be", "");
   if (inUrl.toLowerCase().contains("youtu.be")) {
       return inUrl.substring(inUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
   }
   String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*";
   Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
   Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(inUrl);
   if (matcher.find()) {
      return matcher.group();
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: looking for the solution which can work when youtube link contains `youtu.be` and finally found it, Thank you..

Comment: if your videoUrl is something like - `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs8fsrngI3Q&feature=youtu.be`, then just update your if condition to `if (inUrl.toLowerCase().contains("youtu.be/")) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone. The idea is to first get the videos you want, Here I've retrieved a list of videos from a playlist. After that i used this class:
http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/ 
To display a progress bar while the thumbnail was being retrieved from the web.

```
    /***
 * Fetch all videos in a playlist
 * @param playlistId
 * @return
 * @throws ClientProtocolException
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws JSONException
 */
public YouTubePlaylist fetchPlaylistVideos(String playlistId) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    String playlistUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + playlistId + "?v=2&alt=jsonc";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(playlistUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    String jsonString = GeneralHelpers.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    if (jsonString.contains("Playlist not found")) {
        Log.e(TAG, "playlist not found. id: " + playlistId);
        return null;
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");

    String playlistTitle = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("title");
    String author = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("author");

    List<YouTubeVideo> videos = new ArrayList<YouTubeVideo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject video = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("video");
        // The title of the video
        String title = video.getString("title");

        String url;
        try {
            url = video.getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");
        } catch (JSONException ignore) {
            url = video.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
        }

        String thumbUrl = video.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
        String videoId = video.getString("id");
        String uploaded = video.getString("uploaded");
        String duration = video.getString("duration");
        String minutes = (Integer.parseInt(duration) / 60 < 10) ? "0" + (Integer.parseInt(duration) / 60) : "" + (Integer.parseInt(duration) / 60);
        String seconds = (Integer.parseInt(duration) % 60 < 10) ? "0" + (Integer.parseInt(duration) % 60): "" + (Integer.parseInt(duration) % 60); 
        duration = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        videos.add(new YouTubeVideo(title, author, url, thumbUrl, videoId, uploaded, duration));
    }

    YouTubePlaylist playlist = new YouTubePlaylist(author, playlistId, playlistTitle, videos);
    return playlist;
}//end fetchPlaylistVideos
```