# Getting link info android

Tags: android

how can we show some additional information about a link in android 
i have seen examples that open links in the browser but that is not the case what i want

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String text = "This is just a test. Click this link here <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a> to visit google.";
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

I have tried some code like above but it is for opening in a browser where else i want something like the below image

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do? Presumably if you click the links in the screenshot, they will open in a browser, too?

Comment: used two TextView first one contain your info-text and second contain link

Comment: how can we get the info about a link

Comment: What you need to do is to parse the YouTube link for the video ID and then get the thumbnail image for it. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841159/how-to-make-youtube-video-thumbnails-in-android

Answer (score 1):

That can be done using a [URLSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html).

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("This is just a test. Click this link here to visit google.");
text.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com", 37, 41, 0)); 
tv.setText(text);
```

There are also several types of other Spans that can be really useful to style text. The 37 and 41 are the start and end indexes of the text to style.

Also [here](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/) is an excellent blog post by Flavien Laurent on the many uses of Spans.

Comment: I wanted to display extra info. ex: if the person posts a youtube link then show some kind of image related to the link or som info.PLz help

Answer (score 0):

I think splitting it into 2 text views is the best option. Here is a similar thread:

[android: html in textview with link clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438713/android-html-in-textview-with-link-clickable)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i can make the links clickable but i want more inforamtion about a link to display it in second textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic HTML to format your text in `TextView`. You can do something like bold, italic, link, etc. Here is a sample:

```
String code = "<p><b>First, </b><br/>" +
        "Please press the link below.</p>" +
        "<p><b>Second,</b><br/>" +
        "Please insert the details of the event."
        "<a href='http://www.google.com'>click here</a></p>";

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(code, this, null));
tv.setTextSize(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the OG tags from the link

This can be done by using JSoup and getting the information about the link and then extracting the OG tags from that.

You can checkout a simple library I made for the same task.

https://github.com/Priyansh-Kedia/OpenGraphParser